# How to take a single screenshot of a large folder's contents in Windows

Tags: windows, screenshot

I have a folder with 643 subfolders in it, and I want to be able to capture a screenshot of the contents of this folder (in a single image).

Now obviously, even with my 1920px resolution and the sub folders viewed as `List`, not all the folders appear in one screen... i.e. I have to scroll to the left to see the rest of them.  Therefore, I cannot just take a single screenshot with the `PRTSC` button.

The way I used to do it before is take  multiple screenshots of the folder, screen by screen, and then attach them together manually...but this is very time consuming.

**So, is there a way (with an application maybe) that will take a single screenshot of the whole folder's contents ?**

---

I tried it with [Screenshot Captor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) but it doesn't seem to offer such functionality.

Comment: Even if you take a screen shot you won't be able to display it at a sensible size if it doesn't fit on your screen to take the shot, wouldn't it be easier to just output a directory listing from the cmd prompt to a file?

Comment: I agree...screenshot of an explorer window is dumb. Just put it in a text file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The free version of [FastStone Capture](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html) will do this.
Use the 'Capture Scrolling Window' function (which also works on web pages):

[image]

Comment: +1 Excellent, exactly what I was looking for.
Tried it out now and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Cool app, +1 for you

Answer (score 8):

As per the earlier comment, you don't say why you're doing this, but by far the easiest way to do this would just be to capture the output of a directory listing at the command prompt. This also has the advantage over a screenshot that if you want to do anything with the listing other than just look at it, you can easily import this listing into other apps (eg Excel) or run scripts on it.

All you'd need to do is run `CMD` change to the directory you want to take a listing of and then run something like:

```
dir /B > c:\temp\listing.txt
```

This would give you a list of all the files and folders, with no headings, or file sizes etc, saved to a file called listing.txt in c:\temp.

Alternatively if you want all the extra info then this might be better:

```
dir /OGN /W > c:\temp\listing.txt
```

Comment: yes yes i know that, but I needed a screenshot

Comment: visually better alternative would be `tree /f > listing.txt`

Answer (score 6):

A few Screen capture tools allow for you to define scrollable regions for screenshot composition.

[FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) or [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) which are shareware possibilities. Or [EasyCapture](http://www.easy-capture.com/), a freeware alternative

Answer (score 0):

There's another awesome utility that's lightweight and has some cool options like exporting to csv etc.(in addition to the requested screenshot feature) http://www.primeoption.com.au/FreewareYourDir.htm

Answer (score 0):

Someone's already mentioned Faststone Capture.

However, you could try PicPick - http://picpick.wiziple.net/ - it should do what you want (and can apparently capture across dual monitors if you need that too, but I don't have two monitors to try it with). It's free for home use.